# how to map /url/{} pathvariables to Ext Js Store

Tags: javascript, java, extjs

I have a dynamic URL, and it authenticates the token in the controller, get details from the id in the URL and passes along the details to the EXt js store/mode/view/controller. However, I don't know how to format the url in the sotre to map to the java controller.

java controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resetPassword")
public class GmiResetPasswordController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/{token}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public
        @ResponseBody
        User getDetails(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable(value = "id") int id, @PathVariable(value = "token") String token) {
    // [..]
    return details;
```

ext js store:

```
Ext.define('resetPassword.store.resetPasswordStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'resetPassword.model.resetPasswordModel',
    storeId: 'resetPasswordStore',
    autoload: true,
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        type: 'ajax',
        timeout : 36000,
        url: '/resetPassword/{id}/{token}',
        reader: {
            type:'json'
        }
    })
});
```

how do I format this in the store so that it loads into the view? Right now its just displaying the user details as a String in the page with nothing in it.

Comment: You will need to make store load manually because I think that id/token will be generated at runtime(so no hardcode values).Before loading of store you will have to replace these proxy params of store.
Reply if you have some concerns

Answer (score 3):

You need to load this store explicitly when required -

```
loadResetPasswordStore : function(){
    var id = 'idVal';
    var token = 'tokenVal';
    var store = Ext.getStore('resetPassword.store.resetPasswordStore');
    if(store != null){
        var proxyUrl = '/resetPassword/'+ id + '/'+ token ;
        store.getProxy().setUrl(proxyUrl);
    }
    store.load({
        callback : function(records) {
            // Code to be executed after store is loaded.
        }           
    });
}
```

Call this method when and where required.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Now its giving me this: http://localhost:8080/resetPassword/idVal/tokenVal/go.htm?_dc=1488575070491&page=1&start=0&limit=25
error 400
Because its loading the tokenVal instead of the actual string into the URL

Comment: var id = 'idVal';
    var token = 'tokenVal';
These are dummy values . You assign your required values to these variables.

Comment: I do not know the values, they come from the URL. I cannot set the values manually everytime. A random token is generated when the password recovery email is sent to the user

Comment: The variables on the URL change each time, but it always maps to the same model/store/controller, just loads different data based off the ID. I return all the details with the ID from the url in the java controller class, it returns all the data. I need the store to recognize the URL, it loads the details like this in the controller:  this.getUserSettingsDetailStoreStore().on({
            load: function (storeRef, records, successful) {
               var userSettingObj = records[0];
               thisController.loadDetails(userSettingObj);
However, it never gets to this point.